# Override the positional and optional arguments with another argument in command line (argparse python module)

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparser to parse the command line arguments.

Now, I have something like

```
./script.py 1112323 0 --salary 100000 -- age 34
```

Here first two are positional arguments and rest are optional.

Now, I want to have a feature such that when the user gives a filename as input in command line, then it should override these above arguments and take the arguments from header of the file. I meam when user gives sth like

```
id|sequence|age|name|...........   (header of the file with first two cols as positional arguments and rest positional)
```

On giving this in command line:

```
./script.py -f filename
```

it should not complain of above positional arguments.

Is this feasible over my current implementation?

Answer (score 3):

You will most likely need to implement this check yourself. Make both arguments (positional and -f) optional (required=False and nargs="*") and then implement your custom check and use the error method of ArgumentParser. To make it easier for user mention the correct usage in help string.

Something like this:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("positional", nargs="*", help="If you don't provide positional arguments you need use -f")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", required=False, help="...")
args = parser.parse_args()

if not args.file and not args.positional:
    parser.error('You must use either -f or positional argument')
```